# postInvalidate stops working after while

Tags: java, android

I have following code in my fragment that starts thread that updates text on my custom view:

```
startStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("onclick");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while (true) {
                          gpsProgressView.setText(String.valueOf(Math.random()));                 
                        }
                    }
                },"UpdateThread").start();
        }
    });
```

And then again methods in my view:

```
public void setText(final String text)
{
    this.text = text;
    repaint();
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        System.out.println("onDraw");
        //   canvas.drawCircle(circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleRadius, innerCirclePaint);
        //   drawOuterRing(canvas);
        drawText(canvas);
}

private void drawText(Canvas canvas) {
    progress += 0.1;
    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(progress), textCenterX, textCenterY, textPaint);
}

public void repaint() {
    postInvalidate();
}
```

For now i dont even use text value, i just increment progress variable.

And the problem is, everything works good, text updates and my view is repainted. After w while (couple of seconds), nothing happens. My thread keeps calling postInvalidate() and view doesn't repaint itself.

I Added listener to another button, that changes its background color, and after i press it, my view updates again, until it stops.

Comment: remove that Thread and read about Handlers

Comment: This thread is for demonstrational pourporses im calling this in different way in actual code. Point is, this code works well, but after certain amount of time(it might be 1 second, 5 ,10). My custom view is no longer repainting itself.

Comment: ok so use this Thread, you have been warned